# CSS rule for two class names provided in spaces for the class attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

1. I have a button component in extjs.
2. For this component CSS has been set like `class='one btn-exit-cls three four five x-menu-active'` .
3. in that the class name `btn-exit-cls` is unique.
4. when this button is clicked a menu appears which adds the CSS class name `x-menu-active` to the class

I wanted to set rule for `btn-exit-cls` and `x-menu-active` combining both. So that I can apply menu active style for various buttons.

What I am expecting is

```
.btn-exit-cls .x-menu-active {
//some css
}

.btn-delete-cls .x-menu-active {
//some css
}

.btn-add-cls .x-menu-active {
//some css
}
```

I don't want to modify the existing CSS. I just want to override.

Comment: If you want to target an element with classes `.btn-exit-cls` and `.x-menu-active`, then concatenate those two selectors (no space): `.btn-exit-cls.x-menu-active` (Basically, `.class1.class2.class3.classEtc`).

Answer (score 2):

you just need to remove the **spaces** between classes, so it will be like this :

```
.btn-exit-cls.x-menu-active {
    //some css
}

.btn-delete-cls.x-menu-active {
    //some css
}

.btn-add-cls.x-menu-active {
    //some css
}
```

---

### So..

Your CSS code `.btn-exit-cls .x-menu-active` means :
Select all elements with the class name **x-menu-active** that are **decedents** of the element with a class name of **btn-exit-cls**. such as this code :

```
<div class="btn-exit-cls">
    <div class="x-menu-active">
        //some HTML
    </div>
</div>
```

But the other code `.btn-exit-cls.x-menu-active` means :
Select the element which has a class name of **btn-exit-cls** and also a class name of **x-menu-active**. such as this code :

```
<div class="btn-exit-cls x-menu-active">
    //some HTML
</div>
```

This small space between the two classes makes a huge difference in what it does

Hope this will help you ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target elements that have **both** classes, you must write them without a space between them:

```
.btn-exit-cls.x-menu-active {
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, if you wirte it like this:

```
.btn-exit-cls .x-menu-active {
    ...
}
```

you are targeting elements with class `x-menu-active` that are descendants of elements with class `btn-exit-cls`